# SAS Proc tabulate print missing values for class variables

Tags: vb.net, sas

I am trying to create a weekly table with Proc tabulate using a daterange prompt. The weekday is a class variable with other `class` and `var` variables. The problem I am facing is that if there is no data for a date then it is not displayed in the table and thus distorting my table.

I'm wondering if there is a way to include dates for which there is no data. I know about the `classdata=dset` option but that requires values of all class variables and that is also not desirable.

Comment: Are you using VB.net?

Comment: I think you've already identified the best solution - how hard would it be to generate some classdata?

Comment: Also have the preloadfmt option available.

Answer (score 0):

If each weekday comes up at least once with at least one combination of the other class variables, and you are able to produce the required output via `proc summary` / `proc means` rather than `proc tabulate`, you could use the `COMPLETETYPES` option from those procs. Annoyingly, this option doesn't seem to be available in `proc tabulate`.

Otherwise, I think you're stuck with generating a `CLASSDATA` dataset. If you can't use `proc means` / `proc summary`, but you do always have at least one record from each weekday as above, you could use a `COMPLETETYPES` `proc summary` to generate a `CLASSDATA` dataset to use with `proc tabulate`.

Another option possibly worth investigating would be to see whether you could add dummy records to your data, in such a way that they have no effect on the reported statistics.